# Donor personal information exposed in Google searches

Tags: drupal

We have been receiving reports of our donor's personal information (name, address, city, state, zip, phone number, CiviCrm internal contact ID#) being presented in a Google search. We are using CiviCrm 4.7.22 installed in Drupal 7.56. We must be able to assure our donor base that all personal information is not released from our database. We do use on-line contributions, event registrations, regular emails etc. to interact with our donors. There is some urgency in this request.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Find and Fix the problem:**

1a) Check your Permissions settings in admin/people/permissions
Look in the Anonymous User role column -> for permissions such as : View Any Contact in the CiviCRM database; There are a lot of settings - examine them all - and remove any checkboxes for Anonymous that are not appropriate;

1b) It's also quite possible that you've misconfigured Profile/Fields to be listed publicly; here's the documentation for that: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#making-directories-with-profiles - note that for every Field in a profile - you can specify it's Visibility; examine if any of the fields are set to Public (and if so - correct them to User and Admin);

**2. Address the Google Indexing:** get into your Google Webmaster Tools account (create one if you don't have one yet) - and remove the unwanted links from the Search Index.